# How can I display an info only field in a webform

Tags: webform-civicrm

I have put together a webform for signing in guests to a Nightshelter. Some guests are banned from time to time,  and when a known guest tries to get signed in I want to show if he/she is subject to a ban. Simple enough, but I can't figure out how to do this without exposing the yes/no banned field as updateable.  I can use conditionals but still end up showing the field as updateable.  Is it possible to show a field as read only in a webform? Or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use webform conditional rules to display or hide a message based on the ban.

1. Add the "is banned" custom field to your webform
2. Update it from the webform tab to be type "hidden" (but *not* secure value)
3. Create a "Markup" field, and enter your warning message
4. Add a conditional rule to show/hide the markup based on the "is banned" value.

Comment: I hadn't realised that I could hide a field in the webform - learning a lot here!  Thanks.

Comment: I set up the 'banned' field as an (alphanumeric) radio button and before I made it hidden I tested it and it worked fine using conditionals.  When I made the field hidden in webform it stopped working - as though the values become inaccessible.  So this doesn't seem to work - guess I should untick it as a solution - unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Oof, I guess webforms won't use hidden fields as conditional control fields? That sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: Workaround would be to hide the field with css, but IMO you should file a bug report with the webform project too.

Comment: Done, I raised a bug with the webform project - see https://www.drupal.org/node/2606598

Comment: The above bug report was closed as 'correct working behaviour'.  Which is a great shame if you want to hide a field and use it in conditional processing.

Comment: I've reopened the issue - also note that I discovered a workaround which may suit your needs.

Comment: Workaround indeed works - I changed the field to 'hidden element' and the conditional now works. Thanks, you are a star, Coleman!

Answer (score 2):

For select option components in a Webform, Disabled is not an option.

For something like what you are trying to do, I might be inclined to add a contextual block view that boldly states that they are not allowed in.

I also might try to set up a rule that checks that field and prints out a warning.

Comment: Thanks - in Civi I added a 'ban reason' and exposed that as a disabled textfield, with a conditional message if this field is non blank.