# Displaying a Views block with a CiviCRM-enabled webform

Tags: webform-civicrm, drupal-views

As an alternative to "[How can I display an info only field in a webform](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7272/how-can-i-display-an-info-only-field-in-a-webform)", we are displaying a read-only View block on a CiviCRM-enabled webform page via [Context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context) because one of the fields of the View block is an embedded View (via the [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) module).

We are linking to the webform from another view so that we can supply a Contact ID in the URL, allowing the webform to auto-fill with a contact's information.  Per the [instructions for Generating URL arguments from Views](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Webform+CiviCRM+Integration), our link is as follows: `/family-info?cid1=[id]`.

The link correctly supplies the contact ID to auto-fill the webform fields, but does not return any results for the View block that is on the page.  I confirmed that the View block is setup correctly because I can supply a contact ID in the View preview in the Views UI and the block information displays correctly.  **There seems to be a difference between how the webform is reading the URL argument and how the Views block is reading it.  Any ideas on how to make the two work together?**

Drupal 7.41; Webform 4.12; CiviCRM 4.6.6; CiviCRM-Webform Integration 4.14

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much trial and error, we discovered that the webform and Views block both populate correctly with a supplied link of `/family-info?cid=[id]`.  By removing the `1` between `cid` and `=`, the View contextual filter works properly and the webform still auto-fills.  I don't know the implications if one were to try to have multiple contact id's, but for our purposes of only one contact id, this resolves the issue.

Comment: hmm interesting. i think we used some php to do this but can't find it quickly so can't share sorry

Comment: Yes, when webform_civicrm started supporting multiple contacts the `cid` url arg was deprecated in favor of `cid1` but there no plans to remove support for it as it's useful to have in situations like this.

Comment: Thank you @Coleman, that confirms that this can work as a solution and not just a hack we stumbled upon. :-)

Comment: No prob. Of course if the two modules didn't happen to both support the same argument name (e.g. with multiple contacts) you could always do `/family-info?cid=[id]&cid2=[id]` to supply it in both forms.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like we used to do this via the php filter module but stopped doing so for security reasons and have added this snippet of code to a module to provide the contextual filter to the view:

```
function tidbits_views_pre_build(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == 'your_view'
    && ($view->current_display == 'block_1' || $view->current_display == 'block_2')) {
    $view->args[] = $_GET['cid'];
  }
}
```

Comment: NB: I am just the messenger, not the developer, I hope the above makes enough sense without more context

Comment: let us know how you got on with it when you know

Comment: Pete, with Coleman's confirmation of how it has worked in the past, I've marked the cid= solution as the answer because it solved this particular issue, but if we have a form that needs multiple contact IDs along with a View, I think your solution (which did make sense) will work.  Thank you again. I love this community!

Comment: ah ha - good to know - might be useful to us sometime time - agree with the community ;-)