# I only want people to confirm their membership type (or choose another one) via a webform, but no membership to be renewed or created

Tags: drupal, civimember, webform-civicrm

Is that possible via webform-civicrm?

I can think of just making it a webform only field, so no connection to CiviCRM, but then the user does not see his current setting.

I can also think of creating a custom module that gets the current value via API and placing it in the webform only field, but am curious if I overlooked something and whether this is possible without custom coding.

Comment: what do you mean by 'confirm their membership type'? Say I am an Orange member, but the system thinks I am an Apple - what should happen?

Comment: No, it's like: You had a membership of type A last year, which type do you want for this year. If you do not change, go to payment. If you do change, inform administration. They need to approve the change, and then send an email to payment page.

Comment: why not send them to a page/form that shows a block with their current membership and says eg 'if you want to renew with same membership type then CLICK HERE' and 'if you want to change membership then CLICK HERE'?

Comment: Yeah, I guess that is an option too. The reason not to is because client wants to ask a lot more from the visitor besides membership type and that does need to be posted to CiviCRM. To do that in one form is the desired way. If that is possible then we look further and then this is an option.

Comment: Sounds like a webform where the redirect is conditional on a particular answer might be a workable solution. sorry i don't have the recipe for it

Answer (score 1):

You could display a (read-only) Views block on your webform that shows the contact's Membership status.  Relevant links and details on how to get the info to pre-populate are here:

[Displaying a Views block with a CiviCRM-enabled webform](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8444/displaying-a-views-block-with-a-civicrm-enabled-webform)