# Webform CiviCRM country field

Tags: webform-civicrm

Just wonder if there is a way to show country name in country field while keeping the field readonly/"disabled" on webforms? For example, you want users to see their countries but not editing them. The closest I can get is to change the field type to textfield and "disable" it but it shows the country code instead of country name.

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating a link from elsewhere that pre-populates the information, you could use a Drupal Views block that displays the country field as read-only.  (For reference: [Displaying a Views block with a CiviCRM-enabled webform](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/8444/105))

Comment: Hi Allen, just wanted to say thanks for all your contributions lately! Much appreciated! Cheers, Joe

Comment: Thanks for saying so!  Glad to be a part of the Civi community.