# Can a Contact Reference field be utilised on a Webform such that the contacts pre-load on the form

Tags: webform-civicrm, contact-reference

Scenario. I have a field set made up of 3 Contact Reference fields, eg c1, c2, c3.

I have a webform with 4 contacts, cid1 is current user, cid2 etc are set as Static Fields and I was hoping they would show the contacts already referenced for cid1.

On cid1 i have the custom fields set to show, and for cid2 it is set to show c1, etc

The form remains blank.

My test contact did not have a c3 set. So i found a name (component was set to autocomplete) and I submitted the form with c1 and c2 showing as empty (ie existing contact reference contacts were not loading).

Outcome was a c3 was added to my record. So that last bit works fine.

Should the fields load with existing data if there is some? Have i set something up wrongly?

Happy to add screenshots etc if that helps others follow.

Comment: Hey Pete - yes please add some screenshots - happy to see if I can help think this one through!

Comment: PS - not sure if it's possible - but I'd like to find out too

Comment: Where is the link to the webform coming from? From within Civi, or from within Drupal? If from within Drupal, is the link being generated by a view or some other means of controlling the link?

Comment: Related question: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9195/allowing-a-contact-to-update-their-related-contacts-via-webform-civicrm?lq=1

Comment: THanks both. I will update my question to try and clarify but i don't think the latter is related as that is dealing with 'related' contacts, and I am talking about 'contact reference' (though I may yet change to a relationship)