# Current state of Household Membership signup (Wordpress)

Tags: civimember, webform-civicrm, relationships, households

I'm currently working on a new install of CiviCRM to manage our co-operative membership. Membership is paid annually per household - each householder additionally makes an initial one-off £1 investment of share capital which confers voting rights in the coop.

I've done a LOT of reading around household membership and I'm aware that it's an underdeveloped area in Civi - sadly we're not in a position to cover the 200-400 hours of work that [Lobo suggests would be required](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=27970.0) make it work as desired.

There seem to be a few people who've crafted successful work-arounds either with organisational subgroups or using Drupal webform integration to create complex sign-up pages. However, I've also seen a number of people years later bemoaning having taken the 'household route' initially.

As I'm at the beginning of the process and some of the forum discussions are a number of years old, I'm looking for a steer on the current developments and best practice. In particular:

- Is there a recommended route for allowing online self management of family groups?
- Our preferred CMS is wordpress, does the active development of [Caldera Forms](https://github.com/mecachisenros/caldera-forms-civicrm) integration suggest a potential route, or will we have to adopt Drupal for complex webforms?

Many thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 1):

This question has a lot of moving parts, not all of which are clear to me here.  It may be best as separate questions.  I'll try to answer the parts I see.

- It sounds like you need to track the members of a household each as a separate contact.  This is best with Webform-CiviCRM.  However, Caldera Forms will do most of this.  You can create several contacts, and create relationships between them.  However, you can't take payment on the same screen (not a big deal).  I'm not sure how it handles pre-populating related contacts for managing households later - you'll have to experiment.  Worst case, you could sponsor the Caldera Forms devs for a lot less than 200-400 hours for that feature.
- You do NOT need to use the Household contact type if it's not important to you!  You can do this with a "primary contact" who has a relationship to the other family members.  This is up to you.  I prefer to not use households, personally.
- You use the [Relationship Type](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/membership/defining-memberships/#membership-types) feature of CiviMember to allow family members to inherit the membership via relationship to the household (or primary contact).

Comment: Thanks for the response Jon, sorry if the question is a little confused. I'm testing what is possible with Caldera Forms and will report back. Am I correct in thinking that if we go for Primary and secondary contacts that only the primary will be able to renew membership?

Comment: No problem!  See also this question which discusses the feature in Webform-CiviCRM that I suspect Caldera may lack: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9195/allowing-a-contact-to-update-their-related-contacts-via-webform-civicrm.  I'm not sure about renewing memberships through the non-primary contact - I know those "permissioned relationship" [checkboxes exist](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.7/organising-your-data/relationships/) but I've never used them and they're sadly underdocumented.